# listWorksheetNames() is giving incorrect result

Tags: phpexcel

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$worksheet_names = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($input_file);
print_r($worksheet_names);
```

some times it is printing

```
Array
(
    [0] => test0
)
```

some times it is printing 
Array
(
    [0] => test0
    [1] => test1
    [2] =>test2
)

there are total 3 sheets in my excel file..test0, test1, test2

any idea why it is happening?

Comment: No idea whatsoever, and without more information it's difficult to help... however PHP should not be inconsistent. It shouldn't list one worksheet on some occasions and three on other occasions. What else might you be doing that could affect this? Is this always with the same workbook?